# Trello - How to sort activity/cards in a range of dates?

Tags: trello

I would like to sort the activity of my team members on Trello on a weekly basis so that I can either have a direct URL to the sorted activity, or otherwise have a simple selection process from the Trello board to sort this way.

So far, I've played with:

- setting the `Filter by Due Date` option on the boards
- linking directly to a member's profile page and viewing their activity there.

I'm asking because I will be linking to our Trello activity from off-site, and I would like to provide a link to the most relevant activity (per-team member) possible.  My above attempts don't provide quite the behaviors that I want, but I wanted to ask if there was an alternative method before playing with the [API](https://trello.com/docs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an application ([Trello Calendar](https://trellocalendar-francois2metz.dotcloud.com/)) that will work for my purposes, provided that you assign each card a due date.  Note that this does display cards instead of activity.

Trello Calendar shows Cards by Due Date in a Calendar format, which solves my "range of date" problem in an intuitive, visual way that my team would be familiar with.  In addition, it seems that this data can be transferred to a Google Calendar, which will effectively let me display this data off-site.  If anyone wants to view more specific activity per-user, they can do so by accessing the cards.  Simple.

Here's the [GitHub](https://github.com/francois2metz/trello-calendar) for the project, if anyone's interested.

---

If anyone is interested in an in-app solution, Trello [recently added a Calendar feature](http://blog.trello.com/introducing-power-ups-calendar-card-aging-and-more/).